# How to improve chef erb templating performance over large data

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, erb, knife

Edit: I am trying to render really large number of host nagios files based on the  host info from chef server with search api. My main problem is that i have very large number of nodes connected to my chef server around 10000 nodes. I am trying to create nagios host files using search api and then render host templates. I am seeing very long time performing the converge for every run interval, I am currently running nagiosserver cookbook on nagios server which is almost taking more than 90minutes. 
What is the best approach for this scenario, how can I decrease the build time. please advice.

Thanks

Comment: So I am still unclear as to what the actual issue is here other than it appears you are concerned about the fact that your code can only process approximately 2 nodes a second (which depending on what is actually happening) seems fairly fast to me.

Comment: My only concern is the build time. I would like to reduce   the build time for which I am looking out for more processing of templates in less time. Would like to get some suggestion on such implementation

Comment: Are you sure it's the template rendering? The first thing I would do is optimize the search query with bigger page sizes and `filter_keys`.

Comment: Looking at the timestamps of templating from client log, I am seeing the query is taking 30 seconds to fetch (which is not at all an issue for me) while the templating start time and end time shows more 
Than  90minutes.

Comment: Seriously, you do try to render 10k files on a machine already doing a bunch of IO (network mainly) every 5 mins or so over those 10k hosts and you're wondering why you have an IO bottleneck ? Just check the load on your nagios host, I would bet it's over the number of available cores and as such its not surprising you're ending up with delays.

Comment: @tensabai We have distributed monitoring in place where the checks are being done from another tier of servers (gearman). CPU load is fine as its a distributed setup and we are running on physical server. Its not due to the load for us as i can confirm that. My concern is to move template rendering rate from 2 per second to 6.

Comment: CPU load may be fine, IO load is likely to be killed with blocking IOs to/from satellites and disks IOs to store nagios logs and render the templates. Without any clue of what you're doing in the templates it's divination to guess what's happening. And I'll take your words about the load even if I doubt it (would be curious of what `uptime` returns and how much cores are available).